# correct syntax for sass bootstrap override menu code

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, overriding, focus

I'm working on a custom bootstrap menu and for some reason, I can not change any styles of the menu item once the user is on the item.
Is there something wrong with my syntax, its Monday morning so maybe I'm tired and have a simple mistake but I can't see it.

```
 .navbar-inverse {
  .navbar-nav {
    padding: 10px !important;
    a {
      &:hover {
        border-bottom: solid green 3px !important;
        color: $my-white !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: transparent !important;
      }
      &:active {
        border-bottom: solid green 3px !important;
        color: $my-white !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: transparent !important;
      }
      &:focus {
        border-bottom: solid green 3px !important;
        color: $my-white !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: transparent !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can work it with css, for example

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
```

border-bottom: solid green 3px !important;
  color: $my-white !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

but not in sass, why is this ?

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to find out if these rules don’t apply at all, or if they are maybe being overwritten by other stuff with higher specificity.

Comment: _“I can work it with css […] but not in sass, why is this ?”_ - because you are creating different selectors in your SASS, than what this static CSS shows.

Comment: @04FS I have, its not even been seen, unless I write it in css but not in sass

Comment: @04FS the static is showing the same as my css,however i would like this in sass

Comment: Start by introducing the `active` class from your static CSS, because that is not going to magically appear in your SASS output on its own, unless _you_ actually put it in there. And the child combinator is going to need an additional `&` in SASS, to achieve that kind of output with this nesting.

Comment: @04FS sory, can you give a example ? I think i follow you, but would be easier to see